# Gantt chart using pgfgantt with years divided into quarters?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, calendar

I'm preparing a Gantt chart for a two year project; at this stage the timeline is pretty rough, and I'd like to set up the chart with three rows at the top: the title, the years, and then the quarters in each year.  I don't want individual months anywhere.

I could of course do this directly with TiKZ and not bother with `pgfgantt`, but on the other hand it would be very nice to be able to use the nice functions which `pgfgantt` provides.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Do you want a gantt chart using pgfgantt?

Answer (score 44):

This is an attempt, hoping it will serve as a starting point. For more detail, please refer to its manual [PgfGantt](http://bay.uchicago.edu/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf).   `inline=false` means to write the label on the left edge.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\ganttset{group/.append style={orange},
milestone/.append style={red},
progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red}}

\begin{document}

%    \begin{figure}
%    \centering
     \begin{ganttchart}[%Specs
     y unit title=0.5cm,
     y unit chart=0.7cm,
     vgrid,hgrid,
     title height=1,
%     title/.style={fill=none},
     title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
     bar/.style={fill=blue},
     bar height=0.7,
%   progress label text={},
     group right shift=0,
     group top shift=0.7,
     group height=.3,
     group peaks width={0.2},
     inline]{1}{24}
    %labels
    \gantttitle{A two-years project}{24}\\  % title 1
    \gantttitle[]{2013}{12}                 % title 2
    \gantttitle[]{2014}{12} \\              
    \gantttitle{Q1}{3}                      % title 3
    \gantttitle{Q2}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q3}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q4}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q1}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q2}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q3}{3} 
    \gantttitle{Q4}{3}\\
    % Setting group if any
    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 1}{1}{5}\\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=10,inline=false]{Planning}{1}{4}\\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 1}{9} \\

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 2}{6}{12} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=2,inline=false]{test1}{10}{19} \\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 2}{17} \\
    \ganttbar[progress=5,inline=false]{test2}{11}{20} \\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 3}{22} \\       

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 3}{13}{24} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=90,inline=false]{Task A}{13}{15} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=50,inline=false, bar progress label node/.append style={below left= 10pt and 7pt}]{Task B}{13}{24} \\ \\
    \ganttbar[progress=30,inline=false]{Task C}{15}{16}\\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=70,inline=false]{Task D}{18}{20} \\ 
\end{ganttchart}
%    \caption{Gantt diagram for 2013--2014 Project}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's also ``\gantttitlelist{"Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"}{3} \\``.

Comment: Can boxes have border?