# How to globally define different task bar colors in a gantt chart?

Tags: macros, errors, optional-arguments, pgfgantt, arguments

I've been working with this gantt chart example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209241/gantt-chart-using-pgfgantt-with-years-divided-into-quarters). I would like to add user specific colore bars. Essentially, I don't want to have to type `bar/.append style={fill=green}` into every new bar command. I would like to just pass a simple command argument to `\ganttbar`. As an example

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\ganttset{group/.append style={orange},
milestone/.append style={red},
progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red}}

\newcommand{\USERtask}{bar/.append style={fill=green}}

\begin{document}

%    \begin{figure}
%    \centering
     \begin{ganttchart}[%Specs
     y unit title=0.5cm,
     y unit chart=0.7cm,
     vgrid,hgrid,
     title height=1,
%     title/.style={fill=none},
     title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
     bar/.style={fill=blue},
     bar height=0.7,
%   progress label text={},
     group right shift=0,
     group top shift=0.7,
     group height=.3,
     group peaks width={0.2},
     inline]{1}{24}
    %labels
    \gantttitle{A two-years project}{24}\\  % title 1
    \gantttitle[]{2013}{12}                 % title 2
    \gantttitle[]{2014}{12} \\              
    \gantttitle{Q1}{3}                      % title 3
    \gantttitle{Q2}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q3}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q4}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q1}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q2}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q3}{3} 
    \gantttitle{Q4}{3}\\
    % Setting group if any
    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 1}{1}{5}\\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=10,inline=false]{Planning}{1}{4}\\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 1}{9} \\

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 2}{6}{12} \\
    %
    % QUESTION IS HERE
    %\ganttbar[progress=20,inline=false]{test1}{10}{19} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=20,inline=false,\USERtask]{test1}{10}{19} \\
    %
    %
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 2}{17} \\
    \ganttbar[progress=5,inline=false]{test2}{11}{20} \\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 3}{22} \\       

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 3}{13}{24} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=90,inline=false]{Task A}{13}{15} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=50,inline=false, bar progress label node/.append style={below left= 10pt and 7pt}]{Task B}{13}{24} \\ \\
    \ganttbar[progress=30,inline=false]{Task C}{15}{16}\\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=70,inline=false]{Task D}{18}{20} \\ 
\end{ganttchart}
%    \caption{Gantt diagram for 2013--2014 Project}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

where I tried to create a new command

```
\newcommand{\USERtask}{bar/.append style={fill=green}}
```

then within the document gantt environment, I tried to call the command

```
\ganttbar[progress=20,inline=false,\USERtask]{test1}{10}{19}
```

but it spits out an error " I do not know the key '/pgfgantt/bar/.append style={fill=green}' and I am going to ignore it."

How can I pass a global argument to `\ganttbar[ ]` instead of typing `\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=green}]` everywhere?

Comment: Please provide a complete example i.e. code for a minimal document we can compile to produce that error.

Comment: I gave a link to the complete example. You just have to add in the new command, then call it as an argument. In the first sentence "here"

Comment: That is not a complete example which produces the error when I try to compile it. In any case, it would be better to give it here. Link to attribute it, but keep this question self-contained. Otherwise, it becomes useless if the linked content changes. If somebody adds another answer there, how do we here know which code you used? In any case, a pain to have to try to patch together what you might or might not have done from fragments, which is all we have right now.

Comment: Better to make a style shortcut so you can say something like `user task=green`.

Comment: I added the working example. If you compile it as is, it will spit the error. If you switch the comments below where I marked "% QUESTION IS HERE", it will compile and run

Comment: What is wrong with just having `user task` do `bar/.append style={...}`? Why do you want a macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a style rather than a macro. I'm not sure why this isn't an option - you already have a number of styles doing not dissimilar things.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\ganttset{
  group/.append style={orange},
  milestone/.append style={red},
  progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red},
  user task/.style={bar/.append style={fill=green}},
}

\newcommand{\USERtask}{bar/.append style={fill=green}}

\begin{document}
     \begin{ganttchart}[%Specs
     y unit title=0.5cm,
     y unit chart=0.7cm,
     vgrid,hgrid,
     title height=1,
     title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
     bar/.style={fill=blue},
     bar height=0.7,
     group right shift=0,
     group top shift=0.7,
     group height=.3,
     group peaks width={0.2},
     inline]{1}{24}
    %labels
    \gantttitle{A two-years project}{24}\\  % title 1
    \gantttitle[]{2013}{12}                 % title 2
    \gantttitle[]{2014}{12} \\
    \gantttitle{Q1}{3}                      % title 3
    \gantttitle{Q2}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q3}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q4}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q1}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q2}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q3}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q4}{3}\\
    % Setting group if any
    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 1}{1}{5}\\
    \ganttbar[progress=10,inline=false]{Planning}{1}{4}\\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 1}{9} \\

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 2}{6}{12} \\
    %
    % QUESTION IS HERE
    %\ganttbar[progress=20,inline=false]{test1}{10}{19} \\
    \ganttbar[progress=20,inline=false,user task]{test1}{10}{19} \\
    %
    %
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 2}{17} \\
    \ganttbar[progress=5,inline=false]{test2}{11}{20} \\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 3}{22} \\

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 3}{13}{24} \\
    \ganttbar[progress=90,inline=false]{Task A}{13}{15} \\
    \ganttbar[progress=50,inline=false, bar progress label node/.append style={below left= 10pt and 7pt}]{Task B}{13}{24} \\ \\
    \ganttbar[progress=30,inline=false]{Task C}{15}{16}\\
    \ganttbar[progress=70,inline=false]{Task D}{18}{20} \\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image: green bar]

If you want to be able to specify the colour, rather than it always being green, you can use

```
user task/.style={bar/.append style={fill=#1}},
```

and then say

```
user task=green
```

to do the same thing, which is obviously a bit more flexible and probably closer to what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to do. Didn't know that was an option.

Comment: Should I change the title of the question...your solution solved my problem, but doesn't technically answer the question.

Comment: It is up to you. I took it to be an XY problem i.e. you were asking how to X because you wanted to Y and thought X the best way to Y. However, Xing is actually quite hard here, whereas Zing is easy and you can Y by Zing instead. But it is your question. What I'd recommend is changing the question so you ask how to do what needed to be done, rather than how to implement a solution in a particularly awkward and tricky way. (Anything Ti*k*Z means expansion nightmares, best avoided when at all possible!)