# Gantt chart spacing, time unit change

Tags: formatting, pgfgantt, charts, gantt

The chart being produced is too wide, I only neede the unit of time every three-six months rather than every month? what is the valid format of the time unit to change this? e.g. i have tried 'x3 month' '3*month' etc.many thanks[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\centerline{
\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,
vgrid,
time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
time slot unit=month]{2020-03}{2023-9}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month} \\
\ganttbar{Literature Review}{2020-03}{2020-09}
\end{ganttchart}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: According to the documentation of `pgfgantt`, `time slot unit` currently only accepts `day`, `month`  and `year`.

Comment: okay thanks so is there some other way to do what I am wanting to do?

Comment: Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209241/gantt-chart-using-pgfgantt-with-years-divided-into-quarters

Comment: no, many thanks that does it !